# Add custom font css with @font-face NOT WORKING

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

I'm trying to load a custom font from [DaFont.com (CaviarDreams)][1], with @font-face in css. I use this: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and I get this in css:

```css
/*! Generated by Font Squirrel (https://www.fontsquirrel.com) on July 13, 2018 */



@font-face {
    font-family: 'caviar';
    src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.svg#caviar_dreamsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
p   {
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:caviar;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
 <title>test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>test<p>
</body>
</html>
```

But it don't work!

(edited)
Can you help me?

Comment: Have you checked your Dev Tools, do you have any 404 errors in network tab.

Comment: No, I don't have this error...

Comment: Also you added a class in css '.p' but only have a tag p in html. it will never apply it to your test text.

Comment: I modified it, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after testing it on my site I have found a few issues:

- Your css class for p is not correct.
- In the font url list you have comma separeeted insted of semicolumn
- I have tried the same steps as you have, and get only woff and woff2 files. (So you need to remove the eot,svg paths from css)

My code fo one example:

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'caviar';
  src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  src: url('font/caviardreams-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

p{
  font-family:caviar;
    font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
</style>

<div>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: it still doesn't work... but try with a link to .ttf:

Comment: <style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'caviar';
  src: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/464456636518498305/467083101034774538/CaviarDreams.ttf")
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

p{
  font-family:caviar;
    font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
</style>

<div>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>

Comment: the link is just downloading the ttf. But if I add it it works. How is your structure of files is your html file in the same level as the font directory. And are the fonts in there with the correct names.